# how to integrate a function in an option of a menu?

Tags: function, powershell

So basically i created a function that displays a menu with different options ; here is the script

```
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'back to school'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $title ================"
    
    Write-Host "1: Press '1' to calculate the missing length of a triangle."
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' to Calculate the area of a circle with a given diameter ."
    Write-Host "3: Press '3' to Calculate the volume of a cylinder from a given diameter and height. ."
    Write-Host "4: Press '4' to Calculate the volume of a sphere with a given diameter ."
    write-host "5: Press '5' to Calculate the factorial of an integer ."
    write-host "Q: Press 'Q' to exit"
    $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($selection)
 {
     '1' {
         'You chose option #1'
     } '2' {
         'You chose option #2'
     } '3' {
         'You chose option #3'
     } '4' {
         'You chose option #4'
         
     }  '5' {'You chose option #5'
     }  'q' { return
        
     }
  }   

}
```

And I want to integrate this function in option #1 ; that's the function pythagore.

```
$length1=read-host "enter first length"
$length2=read-host "enter second length"
Function pythagore {
    
    if ($Length1 -lt 1) { $Length1 = 1 } 
    if ($Length2 -lt 1) { $Length2 = 1 }
     $length3 = ([math]::Sqrt(([math]::Pow($Length1, 2)) + (([math]::Pow($Length2, 2)))))
     write-host "The missing length is $length3"

}
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by parameterizing your function properly:

```
function pythagore {
    param(
        $Length1 = $(Read-Host "enter first length"),
        $Length2 = $(Read-Host "enter second length")
    )
    
    if ($Length1 -lt 1) { $Length1 = 1 } 
    if ($Length2 -lt 1) { $Length2 = 1 }
     $length3 = ([math]::Sqrt(([math]::Pow($Length1, 2)) + (([math]::Pow($Length2, 2)))))
     write-host "The missing length is $length3"
}
```

Then replace the string literal `'You chose option #1'` with a call to `pythagore`:

```
switch($selection)
{
    '1' {
        pythagore
    }

    # ...
}
```

Comment: tried but i didnt work . when i do it and execute it , it displays only the word pythagore but not the function

Comment: @DaliLemkecher Did you perhaps put `'pythagore'` (with quotation marks around it)?

Comment: yes it was with quotation marks , removed them and when executed it says error ; it didn't recognize pythagore as function

Comment: @Dali, Is the function not loaded? It worked for me when I tested it. Can you call on `pythagore` by itself?

Comment: Are you perhaps defining `pythagore` later in the script? move the `function pythagore` definition to the top of the script

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
Function pythagore ($Length1, $Length2)
{
    
    if ($Length1 -lt 1) { $Length1 = 1 } 
    if ($Length2 -lt 1) { $Length2 = 1 }
     $length3 = ([math]::Sqrt(([math]::Pow($Length1, 2)) + (([math]::Pow($Length2, 2)))))
     write-host "The missing length is $length3"

}

function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'back to school'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $title ================"
    
    Write-Host "1: Press '1' to calculate the missing length of a triangle."
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' to Calculate the area of a circle with a given diameter ."
    Write-Host "3: Press '3' to Calculate the volume of a cylinder from a given diameter and height. ."
    Write-Host "4: Press '4' to Calculate the volume of a sphere with a given diameter ."
    write-host "5: Press '5' to Calculate the factorial of an integer ."
    write-host "Q: Press 'Q' to exit"
    $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($selection)
 {
     '1' {
         'You chose option #1'
         break
     } '2' {
         $length1=read-host "enter first length"
         $length2=read-host "enter second length"
         pythagore $Length1 $Length2
         break
     } '3' {
         'You chose option #3'
     } '4' {
         'You chose option #4'
         
     }  '5' {'You chose option #5'
     }  'q' { return
        
     }
  }   

}
```

Comment: '1' {
         'You chose option #1'
         break
     } '2' {
         $length1=read-host "enter first length"
         $length2=read-host "enter second length"
         pythagore $Length1 $Length2 ; why did you put the function in option2 after break ?

Comment: I forgot `break`